# session is not saved to redirected routes after hosting in render.com

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mongoose

I have login API that checks if the user has already saved cookie in mongodb and save the value into req.session using req.session.save() method and then redirect to another route to create response and send to client session data to be used, it works fine on localhost but after I uploaded to render.com the req.session data did not save to other routes.

session settings

```
// headers
app.set("trust proxy", 1);
app.use('/',(req:Request,res:Response,next:NextFunction)=>{
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','https://ayno-chat.vercel.app')
    res.setHeader(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
        'OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE'
      );
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type , Authorization , Origin , X-Requested-With,Accept');
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
    next()
})

//session
app.use(session({
    name:"projectName.sid",
    store:store,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
     secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET
     ,cookie:{
        maxAge: expiredDate,
        secure:true,
        httpOnly:true,
     }
 }))
```

login session

```
  await  client.db().collection('sessions').findOne({ "session.userData.userName": user_name }).then(async returnedVal => {

// checks if there is no saved session for this user, then save his data into new one
                if (returnedVal === null) {
                  req.session.userData = {
                    userId: userVal.id,
                    userName: userVal.name,
                    userProfilePath: userVal.profileImagePath
                  }

                  req.session.save(function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                      res.status(400).json({ message: "session err", err: err })
                    }else{

                    res.redirect('/user/loginAuth')
}
                  });

                } else {
                  req.session.userData = returnedVal.session.userData
                  req.session.save(async function (err) {

                    if (err) {
                      res.status(400).json({ message: "session err", err: err })

                    }else{
                      await  client.db().collection('sessions').findOneAndDelete({ _id: returnedVal._id }).then(val => {
                        if (val !== null) {
                          res.redirect('/user/loginAuth')
    
                        } else {
                          res.status(400).json({ message: "error occured" })
    
                        }
                      })

                    }
                  });

                }


              })
```

login authentication

```
 const session = req.session.userData
        if (req.session.userData) {
            res.status(200).json({
                message: "succssess", data: {
                    id: session.userId,
                    name: session.userName,
                    profilePath: session.userProfilePath
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            res.status(500).json({ message: "error with the session"})

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding `sameSite` option in session options

```js
app.use(session({
  name:"projectName.sid",
  store:store,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: expiredDate,
    secure:true,
    httpOnly:true,
    sameSite:"none"
  }
}))
```